# How can I debug Docker containers in the newer version of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a problem debugging Docker container in a new JetBrains Intellij 2023 IDE.

There is an old way of doing this, but new version does not support it any more:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/04/debug-your-java-applications-in-docker-using-intellij-idea/

I am developing Spring Boot based microservice and was able to debug an app with an old version.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You ALL!

Comment: Do you see any errors after attaching remote debugger to the docker container? If yes, please attach screenshots/stacktraces. See if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-and-debug-a-spring-boot-application-using-docker-compose.html helps

Answer (score 0):

So, basically i manged to circumvent this issue by simply running docker manually with debug port enabled.

According to official support comments, this is an issue that should be solved in the next versions.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, what you need to do is to expose docker port for debugging and setup Remote JVM debugging in IntelliJ using that port by attaching to remote JVM. That's it.

In docker file:

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:<YOUR PORT>
```